# iFrame execution faster on localhost vs IP/Domain

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js

I'm facing a problem with iFrame. I have a Javascript app hosted on Google cloud that renders content (a 3D model).
When I load this iFrame on my machine and use localhost (e.g. localhost:3000/app) it executes at least 2 times faster compared to if I use an IP address (192.0.1.5:3000/app). My goal is to run the iFrame on our application server with a domain (e.g. [www.domain.com/app](http://www.domain.com/app)). The same problem happens also there. I use Nuxt.js 3.

I don't get how this is possible. How can the loading time or rendering time be so much different (10 seconds vs 20 seconds) with the same code, same network, same everything except that I use "locahost" vs. "192.168.0.1" or a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of local DNS/host resolution. Passing through your router/switch takes time. While if it's local on the same machine, it's faster.

Mainly a concern as to how network packages work.
I guess that the quality of your network/cables may also have an impact if you're traveling from one machine to another on your local network.

Is it an issue at the end? Your app will probably be deployed online anyway.

Comment: Thanks @kissu, I added some clarifications to my original question. The app I'm trying to render is hosted on a remote server, so I don't get how it is slower if I run it under localhost or IP/domain.